# Circular Reference - AngularJS/EF/WebAPI

Tags: angularjs, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I'm using AngularJS, EF and WebAPI.  I have a one to many relationship between ObjectA and ObjectB.

In the UI, I want to loop through a list of ObjectA and do something like:

```
 <table>
   <tr ng-repeat="objectA in objectAs">
     <td>objectA.objectB.Description</td>
     <td>objectA.someValue</td>
   </tr>
 </table>
```

The problem is, if in my access layer, I do:

```
 db.ObjectA.Include(o => o.ObjectB).ToList()
```

I get a nice error:

```
 Object graph for type 'ObjectB' contains cycles and cannot be serialized if reference tracking is disabled.
```

Ok, no problem, I just add:

[DataContract(IsReference=true)]

to the *.tt file that generates the contracts (from EF).

WebAPI returns valid values (no error), but it looks like Angluar can't handle the "references" returned, which looks something like:

[
  {
    "$id": "1",
    "someValue": "Pool",
    "objectB": {
      "$id": "2",
      "Description": "Standard",
      "ObjectAs": [
        {
          "$ref": "1"
        },
        {
          "$id": "3",
          "someValue": "Poolhouse",
          "ObjectB": {
            "$ref": "2"
          },
        },
  },
  {
    "$ref": "3"
  },
  {
    "$ref": "4"
  },
  {
    "$ref": "5"
  },
  {
    "$ref": "6"
  },
  {
    "$ref": "7"
  },
  {
    "$ref": "8"
  },
  {
    "$ref": "9"
  },
  {
    "$ref": "10"
  },
  {
    "$ref": "11"
  }
]

Now I can't really modify my DTOs to remove the DataMember attributes for certain navigation properties.

Any suggestions on best practices?  Should I just return a light DTO (just object A), then have a javascript method that looks up Object B?

**EDIT:**

I took a look at the output from Angular.  It turns out it converts the $ref props that WebAPI puts in to empty elements {}.  Something like...

```
[


{
    "$id": "1",
    "someValue": "Pool",
    "objectB": {
      "$id": "2",
      "Description": "Standard",
      "ObjectAs": [
        {
        },
        {
          "$id": "3",
          "someValue": "Poolhouse",
          "ObjectB": {
          },
        },
  },
  {}, {},{}, {},{}, {},{}, {}
]
```

So from here, I see a few options:

1. Change code to only return a singluar object and make sep calls to get lookup fields
2. Set code to null out circular references:

ObjectA.objectB.ObjectAs = null;

1. Write my own formatter to handle the output

I would have expected this to be a common issue, but can't seem to find any posts about it.  Is anyone else running into this?

Comment: What do you mean by Angular can't handle it? What sort of error or behavior are you seeing?

Comment: No error in Angular, it just displays an empty value...

Comment: had you tried with db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;

Answer (score 4):

I ended up add this to the WebApiConfig:

```
  config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
  config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.PreserveReferencesHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.PreserveReferencesHandling.None;
```

That produced "better" json from WebApi (no references)